# Tapping an entry does not give it focus on iOS .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-8.0

Everything works fine on Android, but on iOS tapping an entry does not give it focus. For example an Entry like below placed in a grid. It's visible, shows the text, but it acts like it is readonly. Setting readonly to false doesn't make a difference. But when the entry receives a long tap it does get focus, the keyboard pops up and it becomes possible to alter the text.

```
        <Entry
            Grid.Row="0"
            Placeholder="test"
            Text="test">
        </Entry>
```

Is this normal behaviour on iOS? Is it possible to give focus to an entry with a single tap?

Some additional information. The entry behaves normally in a VerticalStackLayout. In a grid it behaves like it is disabled.

Works:

```
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Margin="20">
        <Entry
            Placeholder="test"
            Text="test">
        </Entry>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Doesn't work:

```
    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="Auto"
        Margin="20">
        <Entry
            Grid.Row="0"
            Placeholder="test"
            Text="test">
        </Entry>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Interesting, i cannot reproduce this issue...

Comment: This code worked well on my side. Can you provide more codes or a demo to reproduce the issue?